# Weird user IDs in Facebook Graph API

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

In the Facebook Graph API (JS SDK), a call to [`/me/inbox`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/inbox) returns the most recent conversations of the user.

These conversations are of type [Thread](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/thread), and they have a field called `to` that contains the users of this thread. From this field I can get the ID of the other person.

I run into problems when I try to use this ID for anything. Usually you can get the gender using `/<ID>?fields=gender`, but with this ID it says, "Unsupported get request."

This ID doesn't seem to be the real one. Facebook says that the `to` field contains [`Profiles`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/profile/), which, I guess, are different from [`Users`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user).

How can I use this weird ID to get the gender of a user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. There were actually two things I didn't know:

1. User IDs are "unique to each app and cannot be used across different apps." That's why they looked different.
   ([link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user))
2. "Gender & locale can only be accessed if the app user's friends use the same app." ([link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#reference-public_profile))

This led me to do two things wrong:

1. I tried to debug my application by making GET requests in the browser, even though the IDs could only be used within my application.
2. I assumed that I had the permission to get any user's gender.

What I'm trying to do is therefore impossible.